# problem while removing content of one list from another in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a list of instagram accounts that I follow but they dont follow me back. Follow returns a list of people that I follow and followed does return a list of people that follow me. And I want to remove followed from follow to get all of those who dont follow me back. But filtering myArray doesn't change it's content. It seems like its elements are in different format so it cant compare them yet they are both arrays with usernames. I've tried many methods of filtering the list but they all give the same result.

EDIT: eg. of array is:
0: "xxx" 
1: "yyy" 
2: "zzz"

```
function follow(url){
    var list=[];
    var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    Httpreq.open("GET",url,false);
    Httpreq.send(null);
var json_obj = JSON.parse(Httpreq.responseText);
for (const node of json_obj.data.user.edge_follow.edges) {
         list.push(String(node.node.username));
        }

        return list;

}

function followed(url){
    var list=[];
    var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    Httpreq.open("GET",url,false);
    Httpreq.send(null);
var json_obj = JSON.parse(Httpreq.responseText);
for (const node of json_obj.data.user.edge_followed_by.edges) {
         list.push(String(node.node.username));

        }

        return list;

}

var myArray=new Array(follow(urlFollow));

wait(5000);

var toRemove=new Array(followed(urlFollowed));

var myArray = myArray.filter((item) => !toRemove.includes(item));
console.log(myArray)
```

Comment: the contents of the array are of string type or not ?

Comment: The type of it is undefined, and when I try to print a single element with alert(myArray[1]) im getting undefined also.

Comment: can you check the content of the array, i mean the entire array

Comment: I've checked it with  typeof. The output is: object

Comment: what are the contents of the object

Comment: "username1", "username2", "username3"...

Comment: you said it is a object right, so it should have key,value pair like  {name:'abcd'} as its content

Comment: `const node` should be `let node` (or `var node` if it has to work in IE)

Comment: Oh sorry, its:
0: "xxx"
1: "yyy"
2: "zzz"

Comment: @ravi why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @Slai, okay I've changed it but Im still getting the same result

Comment: @Bogdanje ,i have deleted  becuase the answer that i have posted , assumed the array contains elements of string style , whereas the array contains Objects which you have modified as EDIT

Comment: Hey, sorry about that. Do you have any idea what should I do? @ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the both cases where the array contains of data of string type and the other way if it contains Object type as mentioned  in EDIT

```
//assuming the array contains the data of string type
let follow = ['a','b','c','d']
let followed = ['b','d','e']

follow = new Set(follow)
followed = new Set(followed)
let difference1 = new Set([...follow].filter(x => !followed.has(x)))
console.log(Array.from(difference1))



//assuming the array contains the data of object type
let follow1 = [{0:'a'},{1:'b'},{2:'c'},{3:'d'}]
let followed1 = [{0:'b'},{1:'d'},{2:'e'}]

let values = followed1.map(elem => Object.values(elem))
values = Array.from(new Set(values.flat()))

let diff1 = follow1.filter((elem,index) => !values.includes(elem[index]))
console.log(diff1)
```